# Split float (1.2) into round number (1) and decimal (2)

Tags: php, numbers

I've got a float: `71.25`

I want decimals to be a lot smaller on frontend and the only way I can think of is to *"split"* the float and do something like this:

```
<?php
$round = 71;
$decimals = 25;
?>

<p><?php echo $round . '.'; ?><small><?php echo $decimals; ?></small></p>
```

Float is output from mathematical equation, so there's no way to *hard-code* this situation.

How to achieve this with PHP? Im open to suggestions if there's a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

$float = 71.025;
$parts = explode('.', (string) $float);
print_r($parts);
```

Result array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 71
    [1] => 025
)
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Is it really necessary to cast it to string in this example?